# How convert timestamp, datatime to number before to apply DBSCAN

Tags: pandas, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am preparing my dataset to apply DBSCAN clustering. Before to do this I need to convert all my features to numbers in order to use StandardScaler(). My problem is that I am fighting with timestamp and datatime. I dropped out the day and timestamp columns and left only the Time column in seconds that appears to be integer. However I still get error like

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Thanks a lot in advance

```
 duration             float64
 power                float64
 duration_2           float64
 duration_2_energy    float64
 time2                int64
 dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I think to the question ;)

Comment: Ok, what is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I have several features, all float and int...apparently. I dropped all columns that refers to dates like timestamp and days that have a different type, and choose only "time" in seconds.

Comment: please add it to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't standard scale everything. It's more often a bad idea than a good idea. Because eyou *destroy* information.

Instead, read the article on **generalized DBSCAN** by the DBSCAN authors. It shows how to use more complex data correctly.

> Sander, Jörg; Ester, Martin; Kriegel, Hans-Peter; Xu, Xiaowei (1998). 
> **Density-Based Clustering in Spatial Databases: The Algorithm GDBSCAN and Its Applications**.
>  Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery. Berlin: Springer-Verlag. 2 (2): 169–194. doi:10.1023/A:1009745219419.

Here, you will probably want to **use multiple epsilon thresholds**. For example you want a threshold on time of a day, and an additional threshold on the numeric attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anony-Mousse. Vey informative. Actually I have several different features and it is the case to make the pertinent choice.